# Get Server Machine IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, ip

In a Asp.Net MVC4 Aplication, How I get the IP of my server, in other words the IP of the machine where my aplication is running in IIS?

**Why I need This?**
I'm working in a project that will be published in a server with a load balance. But there is a background thread that execute some stuff and I need to guarantee that this thread will be executed only in a single server. The only information that I have about the servers is the IP of each one. (Other information is classified for security reasons).

Comment: It is not uncommon for a machine to have multiple IP addresses.  Relying on IP address to be a unique unchanging value is always wrought with problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string ipAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[index].ToString();
```

index is the index of network connection at your server.

Comment: What goes in `myHost`?

Comment: Sory it should be hostName.

Comment: "index is the index of network connection at your server." - What does this mean ?